# Pandas aggregate statistics as new columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` with 3 columns: `A` is an object id, `B` is a flag, and `C` is a value measured on object `A` with flag `B`. 
I want to compute the avarage value of `C` grouped by `[A,B]` and store the results as three new columns:

`C0`: mean`C` (or `NaN`) when `B = 0`

`C1`: mean`C` (or `NaN`) when `B = 1`

`C2`: mean`C` (or `NaN`) when `B = 2`

Below there's an example of how I am trying to transform the dataframe `df` into `res`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "A":[0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,3,3,3],
    "B":[0,1,2,0,1,2,0,2,0,1,1],
    "C":[.654,.123,1.45,6.1,0.322,1.77,9.234,2.54,1,6.77,6.438]})

grouped = df.groupby(["A","B"]).agg("mean")

# how to transform grouped into res?
res = pd.DataFrame({
    "A":[0,1,2,3],
    "C0":[3.377,np.nan,9.234,1],
    "C1":[0.2225,np.nan,np.nan,6.604],
    "C2":[1.45,1.77,2.54,np.nan]})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
res = df.groupby(["A","B"])['C'].mean().unstack().add_prefix('C').reset_index()
```

Or use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with default `mean` aggregate function:

```
res = df.pivot_table(index="A",columns="B",values='C').add_prefix('C').reset_index()

print (res)
B  A     C0      C1    C2
0  0  3.377  0.2225  1.45
1  1    NaN     NaN  1.77
2  2  9.234     NaN  2.54
3  3  1.000  6.6040   NaN
```